# XPath Query for all 'ocrx_word'

Tags: html, xpath

I am trying to build an XPathQuery to grab everything inside of an class of `'ocrx_word'` I have tried some variations and have not found any to work, I get an `Unable to Parse` error.

Here is what my HTML looks like.

```
<span class='ocr_line' id='line_3' title="bbox 165 201 443 219">
  <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_5' title="bbox 165 201 252 217">Associate</span> 
  <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_6' title="bbox 259 202 335 218">Director</span> 
  <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_7' title="bbox 341 203 358 218">of</span> 
  <span class='ocrx_word' id='word_8' title="bbox 361 203 443 219">Athletics</span> 
</span>
```

I want to grab the title attribute and the string.

[Full HTML](http://codeshare.io/bjAO4)

```
NSString *htmlString = [tesseract getHOCRText];

NSData *tutorialsHtmlData = [htmlString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

// 2
TFHpple *tutorialsParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:tutorialsHtmlData];
NSString *tutorialsXpathQueryString = @"//*[@class='ocrx_word']/text()";
NSArray *tutorialsNodes = [tutorialsParser searchWithXPathQuery:tutorialsXpathQueryString];
```

Comment: You should check the string that is actually being fed to the parser, and its encoding (a common cause of parsing problems - try UTF8). The XPath expression doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: I put one line of the HTML into a string and I did not get the unable to parse error. So how would I use the UTF8?

Comment: Alright I got it, changed the dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding to dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath extracts the title:

```
//*[@class='ocrx_word']/@title
```

And this extracts the text:

```
//*[@class='ocrx_word']/text()
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: I am still getting an unable to parse, my HTMl is more complicated than what I posted so here is the full HTML, hopefully this will help. http://codeshare.io/bjAO4  Thanks.

Comment: It seems the 'Unable to parse' error is caused by something else. How are you reading this XML? NSXMLParser? Try putting that XML (or a shorter version of it) into an NSString and see if it works. That XPath expression is very simple and it should work in XPath 1.0 or 2.0

Comment: That's not terribly more complex... And this given answer should just work for it (it does here). Sharing what you are testing/using it in might help.

Comment: I've been using hpple, an Objective-C wrapper. Code posted above.